# Regex to match if a word starts and end with a letter, have no more than one consecutive non-letter (. *')

Tags: regex

I'm currently trying to find a regex to match a specific use case and I'm not finding any specific way to achieve it. I would like, as the title says, to match if a word starts and end with a letter, contains only letter and those characters: "\ *- \'" . It should also have no more than one consecutive non-letter.

I currently have this, but it accepts consecutive non-letter and doesn't accept single letters `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z \-*']+[a-zA-Z]`

I want my regex to accept this string

- `This is accepted since it contains only spaces and letter and there is no consecutive space`
- `a` should be accepted
- `This is --- not accepted because it contains 5 consecutive non-letters characters` (3 dashes and 2 spaces)
- `" This is not accepted because it starts with a space"`
- `Neither is this one since it ends with a dash -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ *'-][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wNxttF/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5B%20*'-%5D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B)*%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?:[ *'-][a-zA-Z]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of:

  - `[ *'-]` - a space, `*`, `'` or `-`
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string anchor.